# Not able to set array as a source to Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I am not able to set following array as source. Please help.

```
var myData=new Array();
myData.push('alertMe()');

myJqueryAlias("#textarea").autocomplete({
    source:myData,
    minLength: 0

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something else might not be working. In this case, source would be set to "['alertMe()']"